# Suggestions for iframe which deliver content according to the parent url?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I hope someone can help me with this issue. So, I have a large website (1000+ webpages) and I want to put an iframe window on every page. My aim is to make this iframe load specific content according to the parent url address of each page on my website.

For example, when the user on my site loads www.mysite.com/Page-1, I want the iframe window to show ExternalPage-A, or when the user loads www.mysite.com/Page-2, I want the iframe to show ExternalPage-B.

Can someone give me an advise how to do it? Should I make a separate php document that will load in the iframe, where to put all the external links? Then, I should take somehow the parent url and tell the php document which link to be displayed. I am not very familiar with php and that is why I am asking.

Thanks!

Comment: Use one page, check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, display relevant content or redirect.

Comment: You have not written what your *issue* is. So far you only have posted requirements but we do not apply for jobs here :)

Comment: some external sites wont allow you to iframe them

Comment: @Dagon I will use external site that loads in the iframe, it is affiliate program.

Comment: @Sammitch I will definately use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the parent url, but then how to proceed? How to tell the iframe which external link to load according to the received parent url?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] because it won't always contain any data.  This is set at the user's end, it cannot be trusted and isn't always set.

You would be better with your referring URL's and corresponding iframe URL's in a database.  But putting a database to one side for a moment you could do something like this:

```
<?php

  function get_iframe_url ($page) {

    $page = parse_url ($page, PHP_URL_PATH);

    /* Substitute the below IF statement for a database lookup 
       if you have lots of pages */

    if ($page == '/news.php') {
      return 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/';
    } elseif ($page == '/contact.php') {
      return 'http://www.yellowpages.com/';
    }
  }

?>
```

Then you can include this on every page:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo get_iframe_url ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think this is exactly what I need :) However, I can't make this works - I get the following message in my iframe: "The requested URL /category1/< was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request" Do you have any idea where the error is? I copied your code into two separate pages and changed only the links in red with my own. Then I tested these two pages - the iframe and php, but I got the above error message.

Comment: Can you view the source of your document and find out what is being output in the iframe src?  I tried the above and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Shouldn't the iframe contain the path to the second document with the links data? I tried to insert the path but it wouldn't work either. Anyway, I think I will do it through a database, as you said above, but it will take me some time to figure it out because I have not dealt with databases so far.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the above works correctly for me.  I would try and get that working first before adding the complexity of a database